# Remove duplicates from pandas dataframe while keeping majority element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

```
   Cat  Date
1  A    2019-12-30
2  A    2019-12-30
3  A    2020-12-30
4  A    2020-01-06
5  A    2020-01-06
6  B    2020-01-06
7  B    2020-01-13
8  B    2020-01-13
9  A    2020-01-13
 .    .
 .    .
 .    .
```

There are duplicate dates in the Date column, and I want to "smush" down the DataFrame so that all the duplicate dates are removed. However, to determine what's in the "Cat" column after this "smushing", I want to pick the majority element of the dates that are being "smushed".

Thus, I want the output to be:

```
   Cat  Date
1  A    2019-12-30
2  A    2020-01-06
3  B    2020-01-13
 .    .
 .    .
 .    .
```

Efficiency is important, I want to be able to do this as quickly as possible, as my DataFrame is quite large (100k rows). There is a guarantee that the number of repeated dates will always be odd, and that the total number of different "Cat" letters can be max 2, so there is no concern of ties.

Comment: PLease provide a full [mcve](/help/mcve) your description is not that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to count all values after a groupby on the `date` column:

```
df.groupby("Date").agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
#            Cat
# Date
# 2019-12-30   A
# 2020-01-06   A
# 2020-01-13   B
# 2020-12-30   A
```

**Explanations**:

1. Split the dataframe in groups according the `Date` using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
2. Apply an aggregation using [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html). This function accepts an function to aggregate the groups.
3. Define the aggregation function:

   3.1. Get the number of values per group using the [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) function:

```
print(df.groupby("Date").agg(lambda x: x.value_counts()))
#                Cat
# Date
# 2019-12-30       2
# 2020-01-06  [3, 2]
# 2020-01-13  [2, 1]
# 2020-12-30       1
```

Note: the result from the [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) method is an **ordered** series.

3.2. However, we actually want the `values` and not the `count`. The trick is to use the `index` on the serie.

```
print(df.groupby("Date").agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index))
#                Cat
# Date
# 2019-12-30       A
# 2020-01-06  [B, A]
# 2020-01-13  [B, A]
# 2020-12-30       A
```

3.3. Finaly, select the first value:

```
print(df.groupby("Date").agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]))
#            Cat
# Date
# 2019-12-30   A
# 2020-01-06   B
# 2020-01-13   B
# 2020-12-30   A
```

Comment: @AMC Explanations added :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution

```
def removeDuplicatesKeepBest(df):
    # sort the data frame 
    df.sort_values(by="Cat")
    # Look only in the date column and only keep the first occurence if there is a dulplicate
    df.drop_duplicates(subset = "Date" , keep = 'first', inplace = True)

    return df
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't forget the `inplace=True` in the `drop_duplicates` method.

Comment: I'm not sure this works... it seems like it is sorting "Cat" alphabetically, and then just picks the one that is alphabetically first, not the one that has a majority.

Comment: @Nahmid is right. For example, if you duplicate the row `B    2020-01-06` is order to get this one 3 times, the output isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider the old `groupby`

```py
df.groupby(["Cat", "Date"]).size()\
  .reset_index(name="to_drop")\
  .drop("to_drop", axis=1)
```

Alternatively you can use drop duplicates with two columns

```py
df.drop_duplicates(['Date',"Cat"])
```